# Change public int value on a selectIndexChange

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Hello and thanks for reading

I have a public int that I'm using to control how many images are displayed on each side of my repeater as a Default value.

```
public int ItemCountPage
{
     get
     {
        if(ViewState["ItemCountPage"] != null)
             return (int)ViewState["ItemCountPage"];
        else
             return 12;
     }
     set{ViewState["ItemCountPage"] = value;}
}
```

This is located before the `Page_Load` event

What I would like to happen is that if we select/click one of my radio buttons, it shall change the number of the ItemCountPage to 6 or another number, so it page display 6 images insted of 12.

Thanks alot for your time and help

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text, out temp))
        {
            ItemCountPage = temp;
        }
    }
```

No matter what I do I cant make it change the about of images thats displayed.

Any help would really be helpful.

Comment: All I see is code to set the value in the viewstate, where is the code that changes the images?

Comment: The ItemCountPage sets how many images that is displayed on each page.

The images are loaded from the database but thats not the point.

I have 2 radio buttons that should display either 6 or 12 images for each page.

Comment: Have you debugged to see if ItemCountPage is being set correctly?

Comment: If i run the Debug it confirms that the ItemCountPage = temp; returns either 12 or 6 depends on what value i select.

Comment: OK great, then you code you are showing is not the problem - how do you display the images?

Comment: I found a way to solve it, i had forgot to trigger the fuction when u selected a value. just added BringData(); But thanks everyone for your time and help

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to trigger my function.

```
BringData();
```